# Marketing Cloud - SQL - Merge values from three columns into one

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, string

I'd need to bring together the values out of three existing columns (extract from a data warehouse) into a new column in order to create the required e-mail address. The e-email address as such is not directly available in the data warehouse. However, it can be assembled by "merging" the given values in the three existing columns.

Basically, I have a table with three columns in the original state.
[image: Output from DWH]

Out of these three columns the required email address can be put together - to be finally reflected in a fourth column (not existent in the initial state).

In Excel this would have been an easy exercise by using the auto-fill function, however, in the real case scenario there is no way to use this function as the extract is directly transferred from the data warehouse into Marketing Cloud. Therefore, I'd need to leverage SQL to "assemble" the targeted fourth column - here e-mail address (see targeted result below):

[image: Targeted Result]

Does anyone have any suggestions how to get this done in SQL, i.e. the syntax? Plus any way to get this done via Automation Studio here and NOT by making use of Query Studio?

Note: The value for column A & C is always the same, whereas the value in column B is unique.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the fields are never null, it's simply:

```sql
Concat(PO, ID, Domain) as NewColumn
```

Comment: Thanks for falling back on this!

When conducting this query I received the column's names concatenated in a new column - meaning "P0IDDomain" as a value under the newly created column.

Any idea how to merge the given values of the three columns - i.e. the rows - instead of merging the columns' names? The expected result should provide something like "P0123123@gmail.com" in the first row under the newly created column and so forth as reflected in the second image under column D.

Comment: @ambra2080 sorry, my bad - I put the column names in single quotes, so they were treated like strings and not column references... try the updated code: `Concat(PO, ID, Domain) as NewColumn`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance. Do you have any idea why Marketing Cloud is not accepting the syntax without single quotes as given with the newest update? In contrast, it is getting accepted with single quotes, i.e. no error message is thrown.

I get the following error code when clicking on "Validate Syntax" with the newest update:
An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Invalid column name 'P0'.

Comment: The following seemed to solve the issue - thank you!

`SELECT
PO,
    ID,
    Domain,
    CONCAT(P0, id, domain) as NewColumn
FROM TableName`